# Targeting specific text in the HTML and changing with Jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I target the text 'Email me when available' and change to 'Email me when in stock' in the following HTML?:

```
<div class="email_back_in_stock_button">
    <a href="a-dynamic-url" class="button btn btn_primary btn_large">Email me when available</a>
</div>
```

I tried using the parent class (as it's unique even though it's a class) and swapped out the containing HTML, but realised that the URL is dynamic, so I can't do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main .email_back_in_stock_button').html('<a href="dynamic url here" class="button btn btn_primary btn_large">Email me when in stock</a>');
});
```

Is there a way I can change the text and leave the URL part intact?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: `$('#main .email_back_in_stock_button a').text('Hello');`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get down to `<a>` and use [`jQuery.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main .email_back_in_stock_button a').text('Email me when in stock');
});
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work. Now it does. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks Amit :)

Comment: @AdamC do mark it as answer if it helped :) BTW glad to have helped you :)